# i wrote an edit post view using forms in Django , it works without errors but the value in the database doesn't change

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

here's the Url.py

```
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/edit$', views.noteEdit, name="noteedit")
```

and the view 
i saw the result of the note after changing an it's work properly but after the second print(note) it looks like django don't save it and change it in the data base

```
def noteEdit(request, slug):
    note = get_object_or_404(Note, slug=slug)
    print(note)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = noteform(request.POST, instance=note)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(note)
            newform = form.save(commit=False)
            newform.user = request.user
            newform.save()
            return redirect('/notes')
    else:
        form = noteform(instance=note)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'edit.html', context)
```

and the model part

```
    class Note(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # on-delete work when we delete user the notes will be deleted
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(
        default=datetime.datetime.now, blank=True,)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    tags = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
            super(Note, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and the form.py :

```
    class noteform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'tags']
```

Comment: please show `forms.py` too

Comment: url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/edit/$', views.noteEdit, name="noteedit"), add slash before $ symbol

Comment: i added forms.py

Comment: nothing happens, i stillgetting the same results @bmons

Comment: in your template add {{form.errors}} and see any error is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `save` method, you only call save() in the if statement.

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
            super(Note, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

De-indent the final line so it looks like:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Note, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```